Integral convergence from weak convergence
Let there be a sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. If $h \in L^{\frac{2}{2-q}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, with $1 < q < 2$, then
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} h(x)|u_n|^q \, \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{n \to + \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} h(x)|u|^q \, \mathrm{d}x?$$
Note: Since there is no compact injection $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset L^q(\mathbb{R}^N)$, I doubt that the above convergence is valid.
